# Why do we send 302 on signup and login?

Tags: redirect, http-status-codes

Typically, it seems that most web applications will respond with a 302 if a new user signs up or an old user signs in.
**i.e.**
client ---signup req-----------------------> server
server ---302 Temporarily Moved or Found---> client

Doesn't it make more sense to redirect with 200 or just say Found and separately redirect the client? There is no resource that has temporarily moved in this case, rather they've been successfully authenticated. I'm confused since 302 Temporarily Moved and Found seem to contradict each other based on what their names indicate indicate.

[RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) doesn't indicate anything about the Found status code but only the Temporarily Moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Perhaps this will help someone else.

There are different ways of doing authorization. Some are standardized, others are not. Examples are Digest Auth (in HTTP Spec), Basic Auth (HTTP Spec) and Forms Based Auth.

There are pros and cons to each method. But, Basic and Digest Auth both give 401 Unauthorized Codes. Forms-Based Authorization however prefers using the 302 Temporary Redirect to a login page. This is so that it gives the control of application login experience to the developers themselves.

Forms-based auth is the most popular even though it is not standardized. Typically the client sends a request, server returns 302, client sends another request at new login page, server sends back with set-cookie headers.